# Console output changing in java

Tags: java, jcreator

I am writing a console app in java. Is there a way to change certain lines in the console to new values so it looks a bit dynamic or even clear the whole screen?

The console I am using is the one in jcreator.

Comment: Is ther a way of getting the number of lines in an ouput before you come into scrolling?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739190/update-the-console-window-with-java

Answer (score 3):

You could try one of these

- http://javacurses.sourceforge.net/
- http://www.pitman.co.za/projects/charva/

Answer (score 1):

Once you print it out, you've lost control. If you want to be able to dynamically update it and do what you're trying to do, consider using a JTextPane (or whichever text component suits you best) as a custom console instead of the default console.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only thing you can do is print out new lines with the values you need on them. To clear the screen you would need to just print a bunch of blank lines.