# update the console window with java

Tags: java, console

How can i make java update the current console window instead of going onto a new line (or appending new content onto old).

As an example, if i wanted to demonstrate progress, i would output `progress n` where n would be the given percentage.

Obviously what i would want to do is simply update n with the current percentage. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

```
public class Test {   
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            System.out.print("\rThinking... " + i);
            System.out.flush();
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
    }
}
```

It's not guaranteed to work on all consoles of course (some IDEs may struggle), but any that obey "carriage return" (the `"\r"`) should be okay.

Comment: Doesnt seem to work, i just get new lines each with a new percentage on them (both in my ide and command prompt/powershell)

Comment: Yes, it does not work in NetBeans. But in standard console it works great.

Comment: My apologies, it works brilliantly if you use `print` instead of forcing the new line with `println` ... i really should learn to read things properly.